# A question of interpolation space on homogeneous Carnot group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus, interpolation-spaces

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be the homogeneous Carnot group on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined as follows:

A homogeneous Lie group $\mathbb{G}=(\mathbb{R}^{n},\circ)$ is called a homogeneous Carnot group (or a stratified Lie group) if the following two conditions are fulfilled:

1. For some integers $n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdots+n_{k}=n$ the decomposition $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\mathbb{R}^{n_{1}}\times \mathbb{R}^{n_{2}}\times \cdots\times \mathbb{R}^{n_{k}}$ holds, and for each $t>0$ there exists a dilation $\delta_{t}(x)=(tx^{(1)},t^{2}x^{(2)},\ldots,t^{k}x^{(k)})$ which is an automorphism of the group $\mathbb{G}$. Here $x^{(i)}\in \mathbb{R}^{n_{i}}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$.
2. Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n_{1}}$ be the left invariant vector fields on $\mathbb{G}$ such that $X_{k}(0)=\partial_{x_{k}}|_{0}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n_{1}$. Then $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n_{1}}$ satisfies the H"{o}rmander's condition in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e.
   $$ \text{rank Lie}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{n_{1}})(x)=n ~~~\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$$
   In other words, the Lie algebra corresponding to the Lie group $\mathbb{G}$ is spanned by the iterated commutators of $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n_{1}}$.

Let $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{G}}$ be the quasi-norm on the homogeneous Carnot group $\mathbb{G}$, we define the fractional Sobolev space on $\mathbb{G}$ for $0<s<1<p<\infty$:
$$  H^{s,p}(\mathbb{G})=\left\{u\in L^{p}(\mathbb{G})\bigg|\int_{\mathbb{G}}\int_{\mathbb{G}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^{p}dxdy}{\|y^{-1}\circ x\|_{\mathbb{G}}^{Q+sp}}<\infty \right\}, $$
endowed with the norm
$$ \|u\|_{H^{s,p}(\mathbb{G})}=\|u\|_{L^p(\mathbb{G})}+\left(\int_{\mathbb{G}}\int_{\mathbb{G}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^{p}dxdy}{\|y^{-1}\circ x\|_{\mathbb{G}}^{Q+sp}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

We consider the Folland-Stein space given by vector fields $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n_{1}}$,
$$ H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})|X_{j}u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n}),~1\leq j\leq n_1\} $$
endowed with norm
$$ \|u\|^2_{H^{1}_{X}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}=\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^2+\|Xu\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^2=\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^2+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\|X_{j}u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^2. $$

Assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open domain with smooth boundary. We denote by $H_{X,0}^{1}(\Omega)$ the closure of $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $H_{X}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, and we also set
$$ H^{s,2}_{0}(\Omega)=\{u\in H^{s,2}(\mathbb{G})| u=0 ~\mbox{in}~~\mathbb{G}\setminus\Omega\}.$$

**Question:**
Do we have
$$ [L^{2}(\Omega),H_{X,0}^{1}(\Omega)]_{s}\subset H^{s,2}_{0}(\Omega) ?$$

**Background:** When $n_1=n$ and $X_{i}=\partial_{x_{i}}$, it follows that $H_{X,0}^{1}(\Omega)$ coincides with the classical Sobolev space $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. In this case, $H^{s,2}_{0}(\Omega)$ is also the classcial fractional Sobolev space. From **Lemma 1** in *Musina, Roberta; Nazarov, Alexander I.*, [**On fractional Laplacians**](https://doi.org/10.1080/03605302.2013.864304), Commun. Partial Differ. Equations 39, No. 9, 1780-1790 (2014). [ZBL1304.47061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1304.47061)., we know that
$$ [L^{2}(\Omega),H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)]_{s}= H^{s,2}_{0}(\Omega) $$
for $0<s<1$. Can this classical interpolation result be extended to the homogeneous Carnot group?

Thank you very much in advance!